# Jordan Canonical form with 3 eigenvalues =0?

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I find a Jordan Canonical form of a 3x3 matrix with eigenvalue 0 which has an algebric multiplicity of 3?

\begin{bmatrix}
    {5} & -9 & -4  \\
    {6} & {-11} & {-5}  \\
 {-7} & {13} & {6}  \\
\end{bmatrix}

I get to the eigenvalue 0 with a characteristic polynomial of \lambda^{3}

Answer (score 1):

If the eigenvalue zero has algebraic multiplicity of $\;3\;$ , then the characteristic polynomial **must** be $\;x^3\;$, thus the matrix is nilpotent, and thus it is one of the following:

$$\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}\;,\;\;\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}\;,\;\;\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

In the first case, the *geometric* multiplicity of $\;0\;$ is three, in the second one it is two, and it is one in the last one.

Comment: I got tothe third matrix with a geometric multiplicity of 1, but then I am not able to calculate \begin{bmatrix}
    {5} & -9 & -4  \\
    {6} & {-11} & {-5}  \\
 {-7} & {13} & {6} \\
\end{bmatrix}\{pmatrix}^{2} as a result of \J^2

Comment: You changed **completely** your original question... In your original post there was no matrix at all and you only asked what you wrote in your first two lines! Don't do that: upvote/accept this question's answers *and ask a new question* !